# How to use Serilog's ReadFrom.KeyValuePairs method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

In my appsettings.json I've written:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "PathLogsFile": "./Logs",
         "IncludeScopes": false,
         "LogLevel": {
             "Default": "Debug",
             "System": "Information",
             "Microsoft": "Information"
         }
    }
}
```

and in my startup.cs file in constructor

```
var pathLogsFile = Configuration["Logging:PathLogsFile"];            
var logLevelApp = Configuration.GetSection("Logging:LogLevel:Default");

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()        
    .ReadFrom.KeyValuePairs(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(logLevelApp.Key, logLevelApp.Value)                        
        }.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)) 
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(evt => evt.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error)
        .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(pathLogsFile, "error-{Date}.log")))
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(evt => evt.Level >= Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug)
        .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(pathLogsFile, "log-{Date}.log")))
    .CreateLogger();
```

but minimum-level read from appsettings doesn't work.
Any ideas? How can I fix?

Comment: Please don't force tags into the title. Read the help center article on how to correctly use tags http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: I'm sorry @Tseng

Answer (score 7):

I think you should not use `ReadFrom.KeyValuePairs` and use `ConfigurationBuilder        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")` as proposed by [Parameswar Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3954972/parameswar-rao). However if you really want to use KeyValuePair here is some code using it:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.KeyValuePairs(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "write-to:File.fileSizeLimitBytes","20971520" },
                { "write-to:File.rollOnFileSizeLimit","true" },
                { "write-to:File.retainedFileCountLimit","10" },
                { "minimum-level","Debug" },
                { "write-to:File.path",@"C:\Temp\log.txt" },
                { "using:File","Serilog.Sinks.File" },
            }).CreateLogger();
        logger.Information("test");
```

The important part is that you do not prefix your keys with `Serilog:` like in appSettings.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Parameswar Rao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42875621/4763572), if you are using `ConfigurationBuilder`, you need to use `.ReadFrom.Configuration` method instead of this.

To extend [asidis's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42875621/4763572), you can take a look at the configuration used in my project. The application will load the content of `logging` node as `IDictionary<string, string>` before feeding it into `.ReadFrom.KeyValuePairs`:

```
"logging": {
  "minimum-level": "Information",
  "using:Console": "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
  "write-to:Console": "",
  "using:Discord": "CXuesong.Uel.Serilog.Sinks.Discord",
  "write-to:DiscordWebhook.webhookId": "xxxx",
  "write-to:DiscordWebhook.webhookToken": "xxxx"
},
```

Some points worth noting:

- [KeyValuePairSettings](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/master/src/Serilog/Settings/KeyValuePairs/KeyValuePairSettings.cs) will convert the pairs into `Dictionary`, so be sure not to duplicate the keys
- You need to add `using` entries with assembly name as value before using sinks inside it. To reduce key duplicates, use `using:some_random_text` as key name.
- Full syntax of `write-to` entry is

```
"write-to:MethodName[.argumentName]": "argumentValue"
```

`MethodName` is the name of sink config extension method as in `loggerConfig.WriteTo.MethodName`. `argumentName` is the name of method argument.

If you are not passing any argument to the method, just neglect the `.argumentName` part.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for

Here is a sample of  serilog configuration in appsettings.json

```
    {
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.Literate"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "LiterateConsole" },
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\serilog-configuration-sample.txt" } }
    ],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId"],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "Sample"
    }
  }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to get values of Logging section from my appsettings.json (which is created by  `dotnet new mvc -au None -f netcoreapp1.1` command) and then in **startup.cs** use `ReadFrom.KeyValuePairs()` method?

Comment: the Serilog.Settings.Configuration package, ReadFrom.Configuration() lets us pull the same information from appsettings.json.Only thing is you have to make sure is that there is a serilog section on appsettings.json

Comment: How can I convert my code from `Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()` to appsettings.json in a serilog section?

Comment: @FabioBit the https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer project adds a <Ctrl+.> quick fix to VisualStudio to generate JSON from C# Serilog configuration.